# Proper Way to Hide LoaderOverlay when State Changes from a Provider

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-provider

I use Firebase, the Provider package and Loader Overlay package in an app.  In a number of cases, I have a stream of let's say the the user details from firebase, and the user wants to change their phone number.

When the user calls my await db.updateTheirDetails function, I first call `context.loaderOverlay.show();` to show the async call working.

When the method is finished, the Provider of the user stream rebuilds widget to show the changes coming from the stream from Firebase, which is my desired flow.  no setState.

However, because my Provider changed the state, after the await finishes, `context.loaderOverlay.hide();` is no longer is valid, because the state changed.  I can't just call hide after the await, it fails.  The context has changed.

To handle this, I have two overrides:

```
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AttendeeDatabase oldWidget) {
    context.loaderOverlay.hide();
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    context.loaderOverlay.hide();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

This solution is bulky to include these overrides in every widget where it's needed.  Any better, more elegant solutions?